# Mongo Spark Java Connector Group by

Tags: spring-boot, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

i am storing events on my server from client mobile application, event store is `mongodb`.
I have mongo-spark connector which fetches list of these events and should display them using rest api. It should be streaming for later, but for now i am trying to display it as a single call.

So far i have written my controller as given below:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/analytics")
class EventController @Autowired constructor(val eventMongoServiceImpl: EventMongoServiceImpl,
                                             val javaSparkContext: JavaSparkContext) {

    @GetMapping("/event")
    fun getEvent(): ResponseEntity<EventResponse> {
        val customRdd: JavaMongoRDD<Document> = MongoSpark.load(javaSparkContext)
        val toDF = customRdd.toDF()
    }
}
```

Please help me filter these result given below for rest api:

```
 [
      {
        "key": "Event A",
        "description": "Event A Description",
        "count": 3
      },
      {
        "key": "Event B",
        "description": "Event B Description",
        "count": 0
      }
    ]
```

I have a data set as given below:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e61e38eb8425d3b1c7679ea"),
    "name" : "Event A",
    "description" : "Event A Description",
    "date" : ISODate("2020-03-05T18:30:00.000Z"),
    "_class" : "x"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e61e416b8425d3b1c7679ec"),
    "name" : "Event A",
    "description" : "Event A Description",
    "date" : ISODate("2020-03-05T18:30:00.000Z"),
    "_class" : "x"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e61e47fb8425d3b1c7679ee"),
    "name" : "Event A",
    "description" : "Event A Description",
    "date" : ISODate("2020-03-05T18:30:00.000Z"),
    "_class" : "x"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able on the dataframe to make something like this

```
val aggDf = toDf
 .groupBy("name")
 .agg(count("name"), max("description"))
```

Now on the new dataframe `aggDf` you can do `aggDf.toJson` and have the results. If columns does not match the output you can tweak them with `withColumnRenamed`

Comment: I am getting exception `Error:(36, 18) Kotlin: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public open fun agg(p0: Column!, vararg p1: Column!): Dataset<Row!>! defined in org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset
public open fun agg(p0: Column!, p1: Seq<Column!>!): Dataset<Row!>! defined in org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset
public open fun agg(p0: Tuple2<String!, String!>!, p1: Seq<Tuple2<String!, String!>!>!): Dataset<Row!>! defined in org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset`

Comment: what I wrote it's in Scala, covert that to Java, it should be pretty similar.